# jquery get request returning document instead of XML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a peice of code that i call inside of $("document).ready() in jquery that tries to open an xml file and parse it.

```
$.get('cal.xml', function(data){
    alert(data);
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
});
```

the alert that pops up is "[object Document]" rather than the actual text of the xml which then throws a problem with $.parseXML(data) saying that 
"Uncaught Invalid XML: undefined" (implying that data is undefined).

here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cal>
    <today>
        <event>
            <time>
                6:30pm EST
            </time>
            <title>
                nothing
            </title>
        </event>
    </today>
</cal>
```

Could someone help me simply read in this XML file and set it up for parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the dataType option to xml:

```
$.get('cal.xml', function(data){
    alert(data);
}, 'xml');
```

"data" should be at this point parsed xml.

Answer (score 0):

here is the fiddle hope it'll help http://jsfiddle.net/ah2Y8/1/

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/ah2Y8/2/

Answer (score 0):

code to convert string to XML object

```
function str2XML (str) {
       var xml;
       if (window.ActiveXObject) {
           xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
           xml.async = "false";
           xml.loadXML(str);
       } else {
           var parser = new DOMParser();
           xml = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
       }
       return xml;
}
```